# How to pass object variables for Hibernate criteria?

Tags: java, orm, hibernate-criteria

I'm working in the Spring Framework. How do I pass object variable values into the Hibernate criteria restriction?

This is how I've written them:

```
@Repository
public class EventSearchDAOImpl implements EventSearchDAO<Event> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Session session;
    private Transaction trans;

    @Override
    public List<Event> getAll(Event event) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println(event.getType()+event.getName());
        return session.createCriteria(Event.class).add(Restrictions
                .and(Restrictions.like("type", "%"+event.getType()+"%"),
                        Restrictions.like("name", "%"+event.getName()+"%")))
                .list();
    }

}
```

I printed the values in my output console to check via `System.out.println(event.getType()+event.getName());` and they do seem to get passed successfully.

This is how I'm passing them via my `DefaultController.java` class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String searchEvent(Event event, Model model) {
        Event e = new Event();
        e.setType(event.getType());
        e.setName(event.getName());
        model.addAttribute("check", eventSearchDAO.getAll(e));
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

A form in my `index.jsp` page posts data into the above line of code.

To check if the code works, I added the following bit in my `index.jsp`:

```
<c:forEach var="i" items="${check}">
    ${i.name} || ${i.type}  <br>
</c:forEach>
```

If I manually write the restrictions as

```
return session.createCriteria(Event.class).add(Restrictions
                .and(Restrictions.like("type", "%fair%"),
                        Restrictions.like("name", "%auto%")))
                .list();
```

and make a few tweaks in the controller accordingly, it works just fine. But when I do it by passing the object's variables, it doesn't seem to work. That's my problem. Please help me fix this.

Comment: why don't you try passing the same 'event' itself instead of creating a new event and setting the values?

Comment: @TinoMThomas I tried that just now, the variables to get passed (evident from the output console), but the criteria doesn't seem to touch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a mistake in my Controller class `DefaultController.java`, I should've wrote:

```
return "index";
```

instead of:

```
return "redirect:/";
```

Yes, I'm an idiot.